# Using Autolayout can't change sublayer position

Tags: ios, autolayout, calayer

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

  UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
  CALayer *layer=self.view.layer.sublayers[0];
  CGFloat width=layer.bounds.size.width;
  if (width==WIDTH) {
    width=WIDTH*4;
  }else{
    width=WIDTH;
  }
   layer.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width);
   layer.position=[touch locationInView:self.view];

   layer.cornerRadius=width/2;

  }
```

I just add a sublayer on the view.layer,and when touch the view, change the sublayer's position and size,but when i enable `autolyaout`,the sublayer don't change the position and size.If i disabled auto layout,everything is fine.so this is the question:why using auto layout the changing sublayer can't change position?

Answer (score -1):

With Autolayouts you shouln't think in terms of frames,position,size etc. It all boils down to constraints. To change a view's position or size you should adjust their constraints.

Comment: I didn't add any constraints to the view,just enable autolyaout of the controller with IB.All exists constraints are Top Layout Guide and Bottom Layout Guide.My controller's view is just add a sublayer,that's all.